What are the most minimalistic assembly's mnemonics to make complete turing machine?
Disclaimer: I'm a computer engineering student, not a computer science. Pardon me for mistakenly using computer science terms.
I want to design computer architecture with the most minimalist design as I can. It will be designed in Hardware Description Language (HDL) specifically Verilog.
I have read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine
I will try to translate from CS terms to CE terms, Turing Machine consists of:

Tape, this is same as RAM or Memory, consisting address and data.
Head, this is same as address pointer register.
State register, this is same as general purpose register like accumulator.
Finite table, this is same as mnemonics available.

As far as I read, I think the most minimalistic mnemonics are:

MOV, it requires to overwrite data.
ADD, atleast has one mathematic operation.
JMP, unconditional jump to the specified address.
JNZ, conditional jump whether flag register zero in ALU is not zero.

So, the OPCODE is consisting two bits.
So, is it possible that the word size of my minimalistic computer is 1-bit in memory even though the opcode size is 2-bit?
For example:



Addr
Data




0
0


1
1


2
0


3
1


4
1




It turns out you only need one instruction to build a machine capable of Turing-computation. This class of machines that have only one instruction and are Turing-complete is called One Instruction Set Computers (OISC) or also somewhat jokingly Ultimate RISC (URISC).
In fact, since there is only a single instruction, the opcode itself carries no meaningful information and can be omitted. Therefore, you could also consider such a machine a Zero Instruction Set Computer. You need 0 bits to encode the opcode.
There are a number of such machines and instructions known. Maybe the most well-known is Subtract and branch if less than or equal to zero (subleq / SBNZ).
An infamous example that was never designed to work this way and is a pure accident of history, is the MOV instruction in x86. It turns out that MOV alone is "accidentally Turing-complete". The Page Fault Handling in the x86 MMU is also Turing-complete – in fact, Page Fault Handlers are more or less equivalent to the SBNZ instructions mentioned above.
See also

What is the absolute minimum set of instructions required to build a Turing complete processor on Software Engineering.SE
Minimal instruction set to solve any problem with a computer program on Stack Overflow
Surprisingly Turing-Complete


"It inspired movfuscator, the single instruction C compiler." I'm still not getting the idea, the compiler itself has been created by another turing machine. Therefore, I think precompute or macro programming or something similar where the result output of a program already precomputed, is not classified as Turing complete. There is no branching in MOV>

Yeah, I just read the chosen answer of the second link. I have same opinion with him, MOV itself not a turing complete theoritically, but it does practically (with manipulating another opcodes being transfered so that the processor execute that opcodes)
